# Why does the prompt text not appear for my InputBox using VBA in Excel for Mac?

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I've been building a system that will keep track of student grades, using Excel. I've coded it under Windows, where everything works fine, but when I test it on the Mac version of Excel (the latest version, 15.24, I believe), the InputBoxes only show the title and the text box for the input data; the prompt text is not shown.
Here is an example of the code that I use to handle the InputBoxes:

```
On Error Resume Next
    assessmentName = Application.InputBox("Please enter a name for the new assessment:", "Enter assessment name")
    If assessmentName = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Err.Clear
```

In this case, all that is displayed is the title 'Enter assessment name' and the text box where the user types the name.
Is there a difference in the way the Mac version of Excel deals with VBA code, that would cause this to happen? Are the problems a result of bad coding on my part, combined with the weaker VBA support that Excel seems to have on the Mac?

**UPDATE:** I've now labelled the arguments in the code like so:

```
On Error Resume Next
    assessmentName = Application.InputBox( _
                    Prompt:="Please enter a name for the new assessment:", _
                    Title:="Enter assessment name")
    If assessmentName = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Err.Clear
```

Unfortunately, the prompt is still missing when I run the macro on the Mac version of Excel.

**SECOND UPDATE:** I've found the solution and posted it in an answer below.

Comment: Have you tried labelling the arguments?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav A great idea. I've tried it (see update above), but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, and am posting it here in the hope of helping somebody else who's having the same problem. When I was reading [this page](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-use-the-inputbox-function-in-excel-2016-vba/) I found the following comment:

> Microsoft seems to love confusion, so you also have access to the InputBox method, which is a method of the Application object.

So it turns out that I was using Application.InputBox, when I should have been using simply InputBox.

The following code works, i.e. it displays the prompt as well as the input box and title:

```
On Error Resume Next
    assessmentName = InputBox( _
                    Prompt:="Please enter a name for the new assessment:", _
                    Title:="Enter assessment name")
    If assessmentName = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Err.Clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with Excel Mac Version 16.20 packed with VBA Version 7.1.

Using `InputBox` alone does not work when using `Type:=`

Displays:

```
Compile error:
Named argument Type not found
```

Unfortunately `Type:=` only works with `Application.InputBox`

As a workaround you can see in the sample code below, I am using a combination of  `Title:=` and `Default:=` to “Prompt” what needs to be entered.

Just another option until MS fixes this for Mac users.

By the way, it’s a handy little code snippet.

```
Sub ClearErrorsFromInputRange()
    ' Clear all cells containing errors
    Dim rRange As String
    On Error Resume Next
    rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Not Working On Mac", _
        Title:="Clear Errors From Range", Default:="J2:J4000", Type:=2)
    With Range(rRange)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).Value2 = ""
    End With
End Sub
```