# Prompt doesn't appear in Application.InputBox on Excel for Mac 15

Tags: excel, macos, inputbox

Here's my code:

```
Sub demo1()
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("The Prompt", "The Dialog Title", Type:=8)
End Sub
```

Here's the result on Excel for Windows (I've also clicked on a cell to add the reference):

[image]

Here's the result on Excel for Mac (I've clicked on a cell, as above):

[image]

I'm using version 15. Simply, I don't see **The Prompt** on Excel for Mac. [Some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243489/why-does-the-prompt-text-not-appear-for-my-inputbox-using-vba-in-excel-for-mac) shows that people have been able to use the plain `InputBox` (instead of `Application.InputBox`) as a workaround, but I need the souped-up version because the user needs to click a cell range, and the set variable must be a range object. A plain vb InputBox can't do this. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked high and low for a solution here but can't find one. It seems the Mac dialog simply doesn't contain two distinct sections (title+prompt). I've created a workaround which I'll post, it might be useful if anyone has the same problem. But if anyone can come up with a better solution I will remark the answer.

Firstly we check if we're on PC or Mac with this:

```
On Error Resume Next
If Val(Application.Version) = Int(Val(Application.Version)) Then
    theOs = 0 'whole version number = PC
Else
    theOs = 1 'version number with decimal = Mac
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    theOs = 0
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Then I use the **prompt** if we're on PC, or the **title** if we're on Mac, like this:

```
theQ1 = "This is my prompt"
theQ2 = ""
If theOs = 1 Then
    theQ2 = theQ1
    theQ1 = ""
End If
Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox(theQ1, theQ2, Type:=8)
```

For PC, it works like normal... for Mac, the prompt is in place of the title, so the user can still understand what is being requested. One important downside is that the title line is more limited in space and we can't use line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant to your needs, I had a similar problem some time ago, and I found a solution that works to a satisfactory degree. I've outlined it here:
[Why does the prompt text not appear for my InputBox using VBA in Excel for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243489/why-does-the-prompt-text-not-appear-for-my-inputbox-using-vba-in-excel-for-mac/39271584#39271584)

Comment: Heh, read the last paragraph in my original question. But thanks, your  question and answer did help me.